# How to hide Developer Window when calling Excel Office.js custom function

Tags: excel, office-js, office-addins, custom-functions-excel

I'm writing an Excel add-in using Office.js that contains custom functions and would like to know if there is a way to prevent the Developer Window from opening when I call a custom function.

The blank 'functions.html' page from manifest.xml `<bt:Url id="Functions.Page.Url" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/functions.html" />` opens whenever I call the function for the first time after loading the add-in.

Using Excel for Mac (16.32).

Comment: Could you try if this issue also existing in Excel Online? you can sideload the manifest in Online to try. Did you generate the add-in with Yeoman project? It will be very helpful if you could share your manifest with us to investigating. My mailbox is ruoyingl@microsoft.com

Comment: Hi ruoyingl, it looks like there is no issue when running in Excel Online. I should add that the window also shows on Excel for Mac when running custom functions from Script Lab. The add-in was generated with Yeoman.

Comment: I would also like to see the manifest. In particular:
1. Whether you use a `<Runtime>` element.
2. The body of the `<AllFormFactors>` element.

Comment: The manifest.xml is the same as the [custom functions sample project](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Excel-Custom-Functions-JS/blob/master/manifest.xml), apart from a few changes to URLs (e.g. replacing contoso). Haven't added or removed any other elements.

Comment: @Luis, I modified that sample manifest with proper URLs, and I could not repro the problem. I will need you to upload your version of the manifest somewhere like OneDrive or GitHub gist, and provide a link.Additionally, I need two more things: 1) The exact Excel version from Excel > About Microsoft Excel - the number in parentheses. 2) The Release Group from Excel > Preferences > Experiment.

Comment: If you can also take a screenshot of the unwanted window that shows up, that would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please execute the following command on your Mac machine:
`defaults write com.microsoft.Excel OfficeWebAddinDeveloperExtras -bool false`

You can find more information about it at:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/testing/debug-office-add-ins-on-ipad-and-mac

Please let us know how that works.

Thanks,
Zlatko

Answer (score 0):

After looking into this issue a bit more, I discovered that the sample you have cloned is not good - it cannot work on Mac or Online, where the Javascript runtime is a browser, in which case the Page resource is used, instead of the Script resource. To work, the HTML file must include the JS file, but it doesn't. I am sorry about that.

I will ask the owner of this sample to fix it.

Meanwhile, you can try to manually add this line to the functions.html file:

```html
<script src="functions.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Or, you can clone [this manifest](https://github.com/OfficeDev/custom-functions/blob/master/addins/upgrade/upgrade_appcmd.xml). Since all of its resources are publicly available, all you need to get started is just the manifest. It doesn't require any tools or packages either.

Let us know how that works for you.

Thanks,
Zlatko

Comment: Hi Zlatko, thanks for your response. I ran the manifest from your post, but the window seems to still show. Here is the [screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/JU3C9CY.png). Excel version is 19120802, couldn't seem to find the Release Group under Preferences.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! I'll get back to you.